# Making qualified .pfx certificate out of qualified .crt and .pfx key file

Tags: ssl, certificate

I need to upload a qualified certificate in .pfx file, I have .req and .pfx with private key files from requesting the certificate, and I got the qualified .crt certificate from the company that do these. How can I join the password and the certificate with qualified roots?

I already tried openssl `Openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey KEYFILENAME -in CERTFILEFILENAME -out final.pfx`

output was: error in pkcs12, expecting: any private key

Thank you, this is very important for me.

Answer (score 0):

You say you have '.pfx with private key' but do not say anything about a PEM-format private key. **The input for `pkcs12 -export -inkey` must be a PEM-format private key**.

Extract the privatekey from the existing/original pfx with `openssl pkcs12 -in oldpfx -nocerts` *without* `-export` and either store it in a file and feed that to `-inkey`, or just concatenate with your cert and pipe the combination to `openssl pkcs12 -export` *without* `-in -inkey`.

Note this 'joins' the *privatekey* and the certificate, but there is no permanent linkage to any password(s); each privatekey file (PEM format *or* pfx/p12) can be encrypted with any password you choose (except openssl will usually reject *very* short passwords) and they don't need to be the same, and each can be changed without changing the privatekey (and cert) -- although you may well choose to make them and keep them the same for your own convenience.

Also note that certificates issued by public CAs like Verisign and GoDaddy etc usually depend on *intermediate* aka *chain* certificates, and in many perhaps most cases software that uses a pfx/pf12 needs it to contain those intermediate/chain certs. However, you didn't give any clues about this in your Q and there are so many possible variations of how to select, get, convert and use chain certs I couldn't fit them all in one SO answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a certificate, that corresponds with the pfx private key, but as you said, it doesn't contain the qualified and root certificates from the company. From the company I've got the certificate with the root and qualified certificates, but it's in .crt and the .pfx file doesn't pass to that certificate. The website I'm uploading the cerficitate wants pfx file with the key. I'll try your solution.